# Is there any way to limit cinematics in Fallout 3?

Tags: mods, fallout-3

I love V.A.T.S. except for the cinematic part...

So two ghouls attack me, racing up a long flight of stairs. I pick a headshot on the first one. The other is entirely hidden behind it so I can't even queue my attack on it. I have a enough time and AP to spare to hit both, first one, then as it falls, the other.

I shoot the head off the first one. The head starts rolling down the stairs. The other ghoul reaches me and starts pounding mercilessly, while the cinematics shows the head rolling in slow motion, with my character doing nothing about getting murdered far in the background. Only after the head comes to a standstill three floors below, I'm given my control back and can try re-entering V.A.T.S. to get my second target while under avalanche of the enemy blows.

Is there any mod/trick/console command to return control and remove the cinematic part after the enemy is killed?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: in Fallout 3, during the V.A.T.S. slow-mo sequence, you take 90% less damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in the original Fallout 3 without a [mod](http://www.fallout3nexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=14611)

After lots of complaints they added a kill cam disabling feature in Fallout: NV.

Answer (score 2):

What happens in VATS, stays in VATS.

When you are in VATS mode, the damage you take is greatly reduced. You only take 10% of normal damage while the cinematic plays. Read more [here.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_Assisted_Targeting_System)

Comment: meanwhile the opponent crosses half the Wasteland while I'm stuck in cinematics, and I'm out of VATS right in time to get deathclaw'd.